# In BigQuery, can a child job spawn another child job?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to extract DML stats for a job from the BigQuery API and aggregate DML stats by destination table.  I notice that a script will create child jobs, but is there any situation where child jobs can create further child jobs?

1. I wanted to see if a script could invoke another script, but it doesn't the scripting language (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language) doesn't support this.
2. I wrote a simple script that created a few nested stored procedures and called the top-level procedure but that didn't appear to work.

Comment: Hi @user2910265,  have you gone through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#multi-statement_query_job) ? Could you elaborate more on your issue by providing the sample script that you are using ?